# How to Insert a node from a struct B to struct A (binary trees)

Tags: c, struct

I have

```
struct Species{
    int                 sid;
    struct Species      *next;  
    struct Population   *population_root;
    struct Species      *lc;
    struct Species      *rc;
};
struct Population{
    int                 gid;
    int                 sid;
    int                 cid;
    struct Population   *parent;
    struct Population   *lc;
    struct Population   *rc;
};
```

and

```
struct Species *Species_root; // Pointer to the root of Species' tree
```

Species Tree is done.
I have to do: search the given `sid` from Species tree (I have done it) and when you find it, insert a new node type `struct Population` at the Species Tree. I don't know how to translate into code the part that saying "and  insert a new node to the Species Tree" I know how to insert a node on a BST but this is kinda inheritance  Trees or something and I have never worked with them.
I'm thinking about doing something like :

```
struct Species *spe=Species_root;
if(spe==NULL) return 0;
spe=search(spe,sid); //return the node with the sid we want 
struct Population *pop=newNodePop(gid,cid); //adds  the node
pop->parent=spe->population_root;
spe->population_root=pop;
```

but the last two lines aren't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: It isn't clear what the expected result is. Can you draw your "before" and "after" trees on a piece of paper?

Comment: You don't specify if `sid` is the sorting key for `Species`. You also don't specify the sorting key for the  population BST. `Species` has also this `next` field. What is it for ?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. basically for this event the tasks are "search the sid from Species tree, if found then add new node type struct Population  at Population Tree."   https://ibb.co/hdm98mC heres a link with the Tree. 1st pic : PostOrder Sorted by sid Speices Tree  , 2nd pic: Linked Binary  Population Tree sorted by gid and this is an e.g of population tree with sid 7

Comment: @chmike  check my above comment

Comment: Well I don't know what kind of inheritance tree this is. Nodes in *my* inheritance tree (DAG actually) normally have two parents, and many have more than two children. Perhaps the population tree is a BST after all?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yea the population tree is a BST and Species tree is a postorder tree. check the answer down below , i did  translate it into my code but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a pointer of type `struct population` inside `struct species`, it is done in this way:

```
return_type some_function(int sid_argument)      //dummy function where the data which is to be matched with sid is passed & population node is then inserted to that species NODE
{
     struct species *ptr =NULL;
     ptr = traverse(species_tree_root,sid_argument);  //if sid is found then traverse returns a pointer to that node in that species tree else returns NULL

     if(ptr)
     {
         struct population *population_ptr=malloc(sizeof(*population_ptr));
         if(population_ptr)
             ptr->population_root = population_ptr;
         else
             exit(1);
     }
 }
```

What your code is doing:

```
pop->parent=spe->population_root; 
spe->population_root=pop;
```

Since NEW population node is to be added if sid is found in **species** - it is safe to assume that it is another tree of type `population` is required to be created inside THAT `struct species` node - so, it is an INSERTion which is required at that `spe->population_root` - but say it (`spe->population_root`) doesn't point to any valid memory at this time and then it is assigned to `pop->parent` then it creates and error - better assign it some valid value (by reversing the order of last two statements).

Please reverse the order of the above mentioned statements, check the validity of `pop` and then clarify what you mean by *not working* - I have assumed few things as the question is not very clear.